# Android Studio [EditText] / Como se puede agrandar el tamaño de la underline text + onClick?

Tags: android, android-studio

**PROBLEMA 1:** Como saben, los Edit Text por defecto tienen una línea por debajo que quizá mida 1dp de altura. Me gustaría que mida un poquito más, como unos 3 dp por ejemplo. Intenté usar este código xml como propiedad del edit text pero no funcionó:

```
android:lineHeight="3dp"
```

**Adjunto el código XML completo de un EditText:**

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_nombre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#eceff1"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/color_cursor_perfil"
    android:text="Tomás"
    android:textColor="#252525"
    android:fontFamily="@font/basic"
    android:lineHeight="3dp"/>
```

**PROBLEMA 2 [RESUELTO POR @solamente]:** Además estoy intentando cambiar el color de un **TextView** cuando el usuario seleccione el Edit Text **correspondiente**. El problema es que el onClick me lo toma cuando toco **por segunda vez** el Edit Text. Me gustaría que solo al primer clic, el evento se lanze.

**Adjunto el código que estoy utilizando:**

```
et_edad.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public  void onClick(View view){
            txt_edad.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSelected));
            txt_localidad.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorNotSelected));
            txt_primer.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorNotSelected));
            txt_fecha_registro.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorNotSelected));
            txt_horas.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorNotSelected));

            txt_edad.setTextSize(18);
            txt_localidad.setTextSize(17);
            txt_primer.setTextSize(17);
            txt_fecha_registro.setTextSize(17);
            txt_horas.setTextSize(17);
        }
    });
```

**Adjunto la imágen de como se ve la actividad**, en la cual se puede observar que el EditText seleccionado (Localidad) posee un Edit Text que dice "Localidad" que está coloreado y además su tamaño de letra se agrandó. Repito que el problema está en que este evento se lanza solamente al tocar por segunda vez el EditText.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 2):

Para solucionar el problema2 que estas teniendo debes usar el método onTouch en lugar de onClick para que se ejecute el código que deseas en el primer click.

Te dejo un ejemplo como quedaría con el nuevo método:

```
et_edad.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        txt_edad.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorSelected));
        txt_localidad.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorNotSelected));
        txt_primer.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorNotSelected));
        txt_fecha_registro.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorNotSelected));
        txt_horas.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorNotSelected));

        txt_edad.setTextSize(18);
        txt_localidad.setTextSize(17);
        txt_primer.setTextSize(17);
        txt_fecha_registro.setTextSize(17);
        txt_horas.setTextSize(17);
        return false;
    }
});
```

¿Para el problema 1 puedes mostrar el código del XML a ver como lo has montado?

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por responder. Tu código me fue de utilidad y me hiciste conocer un método nuevo que además es muy interesante. Espero que también me puedas solucionar el primer problema porque para mi sería un golazo!. Ya adjunté en el post el código xml de un EditText con los que estoy trabajando.

Answer (score 0):

**Problema 1:**

Puedes utilizar un recurso drawable como brackground de tu EditText para simular la linea de abajo de esta manera:

edt_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:left="-4dp"
        android:right="-4dp"
        android:top="-4dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke
                android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#0000FF" />

        <solid android:color="#eceff1"/>

        <padding android:bottom="5dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

unicamente juega con los valores de edt_background como mejor te convenga.

En tu EditText agrega esta linea:

```
android:background="@drawable/edt_background"
```

y elimina esta:

android:backgroundTint="#eceff1"

**Problema 2**
Como sugerencia puedes utilizar el método setOnFocusChangeListener, por ejemplo:

```
edtEdad.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                txtEdad.setTextSize(25);
                txtLocalidad.setTextSize(18);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Alfredo, muchisimas gracias por responder. El problema 2 ya fue resuelto. La solución que me diste para el problema 1 no me funciona. Cuando pongo el archivo drawable XML como background del edit text, la underline no cambia sino que se colorea todo el edit text. Podrías corregirlo?

Comment: Si, la solución del problema 2 era una sugerencia unicamente.
Al parecer no funciona por el backgroundTint de tu EditText.
Subí actualización, espero te funcione.

Comment: Y que me decis sobre el problema 1? Crees poder solucionarlo? Es que no me funcionó :(

Comment: Acabo de hacer actualización, prueba con el nuevo código y elimina el android:backgroundTint="#eceff1" y android:lineHeight="3dp" de tu EditText

Comment: Alfredo, infinitas gracias. Pudiste solucionarlo perfectamente. Tema solucionado